# How to write a table constraint that ensures that a row with a specific column value exists?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have the following three tables,

```
create table users (
  id          char(36),
  email       varchar(256) unique not null,
  primary key (id)
);

create table groups (
  id          char(36),
  name        varchar(256),
  primary key (id)
);

create table group_members (
  id_groups   char(36) references groups(id),
  id_users    char(36) references users(id),
  is_owner    boolean not null default false,
  primary key (id_groups, id_users)
);
```

How can I enforce the invariant that every group must have at least one owner? Is this the proper schema for this particular situation?

Comment: Unrelated, but: most probably you do **not** want to use `char(n)` - use `varchar()` instead. Also: there is nothing "magic" about defining a `varchar(256)` there is no hidden optimization for a maximum length of 256 (or lower). The column will always take as much space as the value needs regardless of the maximum length defined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *exactly* one owner or one primary owner, then you can do:

```
create table groups (
  id          char(36),
  name        varchar(256),
  id_owner    char(36) not null,
  primary key (id),
  constraint fk_id_owner foreign key (id_owner) references users(id)
);
```

Trying to enforce this on `group_members` introduces a logic problem.  `group_members` needs to have a valid `group` in order to insert a new member.  However, a `group` would need to have a valid member (the owner) to be created.  You can handle this using triggers or transactions, but it is probably better to find a method that doesn't have this cyclic relationship.

Comment: I want a group to have 1+ owners at all times (and as a result, 1+ members). Conceivably, a user can create a group, and then pass ownership to two other "members" while at the same time reliquishing their ownership.

Comment: @broma0 . . . Think about that.  When someone creates a group, they have to insert rows into two different tables.  That is not entirely unreasonable, but it does add a complication.

Comment: The database should acommodate the requirements, not the other way around. In other words, the requirements are set; the only question is if postgres can model it cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff's answer is correct, but let me expand on it a little bit because there seems to be some misunderstanding in the comments.

In SQL, there's no DRI syntax for *there exists X, such that X is in {Y}*.  By adding an owner to `groups`, you ensure there's at least 1 owner.  But to ensure the owner is also a member you need

```
where exists ( select 1 from group_members
               where g.id_owner = id_users
               and   g.id       = id_groups )
```

in a trigger for `groups`.  But, if you use a trigger, how to create a group, which must exist before its members are added?!

We seem to be stuck.  Why?  The rule *all groups need an owner* is not suitable to a trigger (or DRI) because it's not a rule of *referential integrity*.  The data will still be consistent if that rule is broken.  Incorrect, perhaps, but not in a way that would produce *anomalous* results to query.

So the answer to your well stated question, *how to enforce the invariant*, is that some invariants are enforced procedurally.  It might be the single best argument for stored procedures being the only way users are permitted to modify the data.  Your procedure begins a transaction, creates a group and members, checks that the group has an owner, and commits.

> The database should acommodate the requirements

You're quite right.  In fact, you appear to have stumbled on a long-standing critique of SQL.  It's not very good for building rules up out of smaller ones, for applying rules to whole rows, or sets of rows, or groups of statements.  The industry trend, sadly, is in the *opposite* direction, embracing systems with *less* capacity for logical expression and constraint enforcement.  So the critique is likely to remain longstanding, at least as long as there are people around who know enough to make it.

Comment: I agree that the trend by developers (and some DBMS products) is to support less constraints. However Postgres does not follow this trend - they are e.g. the only DBMS (that I know of) that can define constraints to avoid overlapping ranges. But sadly they do not support check constraints with sub-selects of the SQL standard "assertion".

Answer (score 0):

You can get something like that using a constraint trigger that checks the `group_members` table when it's modified. As you have cyclic dependency between `groups` and `group_members` you need to define the constraint as deferrable so that it is only checked at the end of the *transaction*, not for each row that is deleted, inserted or updated.

This would look something like this:

```
create or replace function check_owner() 
  returns trigger
as
$$
declare 
  l_groups integer[];
begin
  select array_agg(id)
     into l_groups
  from (
    select g.id, count(gm.id_groups) num_owners
    from groups g
      left join group_members gm on gm.id_groups = g.id and gm.is_owner
    group by g.id
  ) t
  where num_owners = 0;

  if coalesce(cardinality(l_groups),0) > 0 then
    raise 'The group(s) % do not have an owner', array_to_string(l_groups, ',');
  end if;
  return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

By changing the condition `where num_owners = 0` to `where num_owners <> 1` you could also enforce the rule "exactly one owner".

This check needs to be done whenever `groups` or `group_members` are modified:

```
create constraint trigger group_member_trigger
   after insert or update or delete on group_members
   deferrable initially deferred
   for each row
   execute procedure check_owner();

create constraint trigger groups_trigger
   after insert on groups
   deferrable initially deferred
   for each row
   execute procedure check_owner();
```

The need to have a trigger for `group_members` **and** `groups` makes this quite inefficient because when a new group with new members is created the check will be done twice. However if you want to allow "empty" groups (groups without any users assigned in `group_members`) then you can get rid of the trigger on the `groups` table.

This is however quite slow and I am not 100% sure if it covers all cases.

The above is more a proof that you can get something like that working rather then a recommendation to do it. But I have to admit I can't think of a different way to define the "at least one owner" requirement through static constraints.

A requirement "at most one owner" could be done without any triggers by using a unique filtered index on `group_members`.